# Joomla! 3 reference materials

Tags: joomla3.3

Does somebody have a complete reference for developing extensions in Joomla especially in Component Development?

I only have the Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development 3rd Edition by Tim Plummer but it only discusses the basics in component development. I have some special cases in our development that cannot be found in the book. Since Joomla! 3 is only new, there are few references and mostly from lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already checked the basic guides on Joomla Docs

https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component
https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development

If you want something more practical and advanced, I would suggest to create a complex component using http://www.component-creator.com and look at the code generated.